# Width of Image View

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying move a button within a `ImageView`. I need to find the width of a `ImageView` and I'm using.

```
        ImgBox.getLocationOnScreen(location)
        val x = location[0]
        val y = location[1] 
        val viewWidth = ImgBox.width
```

The Width I get is wrong and I think its because of the constraints in the `ImageView`

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/..."
        style="@style/..."
        android:background="@..."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1"
```

I can not make any changes to the xml
Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wrote 'ImgBox' as 'OmgBox' here:

```
val viewWidth = OmgBox.width
```

Try changing it to:

```
val viewWidth = ImgBox.width
```

**Edit:**

So the above didn't work for you, so I have tested out this example, and It works for me. Here's what I did.

Add this import at the top of your activity: `import android.widget.ImageView`

Then add this code:

```
val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.yourImageViewId)
val width = imageView.width.toString()
Toast.makeText(applicationContext, width, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Change `yourImageViewId` to your imageview id set here:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/..."
    .....
```

Then you should see a toast showing a number, which is the width of the imageview.

Comment: Hi Amy, that was a mistake I made here only. So it didnt work

Comment: Ok, I'm sort of confused on what you are stuck on. Could you please explain?

Comment: If I wanted to add your code to my fragment I'm assuming it would be the same. When I add it to my fragment I get "Unresolved reference: findViewById"